# Missing vendor/autoload.php in google-api-php-client-master

Tags: php, composer-php, google-calendar-api

There is no folder like vendor in google-api-php-client-master, while searching for `autoload.php` I found it at `C:\wamp\www\gapi\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\autoload.php`

On viewing the source at `Google\autoload.php`, its once again requesting for `/vendor/autoload.php` at line 21 but no folder name vendor.
I have also include the full package by downloading the zip at `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client`

Most of the search didn't provide me a solution, But I found lots of article on this topic. Some one help me on this.

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception **'Exception'** with message 'This
>   library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full
>   package. See the instructions at_ _ _' in
>   C:\wamp\www\gapi\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\autoload.php
>   on line 14

**FILE CONTENT (autoload.php):**

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
  $exception = 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package.';
  $exception .= ' See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.';
  throw new **Exception($exception);
```

Comment: You can learn about Composer at https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Do you have any composer.json file for your project? How did you install this component (google-api-php-client-master) ?

Comment: I didn't use composer to download the file I download the zip file from this link (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git).

Comment: Now I downloaded the Release from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases  --> google-api-php-client-2.1.0.zip got the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\gapi\google-api-php-client-2.1.0\vendor\guzzlehttp\psr7\src\functions.php on line 78

Comment: I am trying to add, update, and delete event from Google calendar, so initiated with a quickstart at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

Comment: Hi I have installed the composer and got the library but getting the errorUncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This application must be run on the command line.' in C:\wamp\www\gapi\quickstart.php on line 17  -> (  if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}  )

Answer (score 2):

You need to download the folder/release from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases and not
[https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

The install guide lets you know about this here:

> If you abhor using composer, you can download the package in its entirety. The [Releases](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) page lists all stable versions.

I did the same mistake, but fixed it by using the latest stable version from the release page.

Answer (score 0):

> > Used composer with command " composer require google/apiclient:^2.0 " to install the package

OR

> > with any of the release at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases

But cant find the package vendor by directly downloading from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client (google-api-php-client-master.zip), use any of the above two ways and be sure to have **quickstart, you'll need guide** at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php